# Drawbacks of hosting an asp.net Web Application on a Windows Client OS?

Tags: iis

Why would I want to host an ASP.Net Web Application, a LOB app for internal company use, on a Windows Server OS (e.g. Windows Server 2016), as opposed to a Windows Client OS (e.g. Windows 10)?

**Background**:
I am developing an ASP.Net web application intended to run under IIS. In case it matters, it uses SQL Server 2017 Express in the background for data storage.

Until now, I have expected to host it on a server running Windows Server 2016, however upon thinking about it a little more I can't see any reason why I shouldn't just host it under IIS on a server running Windows 10. A Windows 10 license is much cheaper and IIS 10 seems to be the same on Windows Server 2016 and Windows 10.

Is there a legal or technical reason why I really should pick the "server" OS flavour? It feels wierd to host a website, albeit a low traffic one, on a client OS, but the price difference is huge.

Comment: `Is there a legal or technical reason why I really should pick the "server" OS flavour?` - Yes. Servers are meant for hosting enterprise LOB's. Desktops are not.

Comment: In this particular case (low-traffic internal website), I'm looking for the answer to "why". Your answer has always been my default one too, but upon getting business pushback I found myself struggling to justify a Server OS here.

Comment: Yeah, I don't envy you. This sounds like a company that places too much emphasis on cost and not enough on productivity, accessibility, reliability, etc.

Comment: No really, it was just a question I couldn't sutiably answer for myself. And when the price difference is €900 it's hard to answer "just because".

Comment: Gotcha. The Windows 10 Eula states a limit of 20 devices accessing services on Windows 10 (print, file, web, etc.) so there's a clear legal reason for not doing it if more than 20 devices will be accessing the LOB. See the Multi Use Scenario section at the link - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Useterms/Retail/Windows/10/Useterms_Retail_Windows_10_English.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer seems to be a limit on the number of devices and concurrent connections that Windows 10 allows:

- The Windows 10 Eula states a limit of 20 devices accessing services on Windows 10 (print, file, web, etc. - **thanks @joeqwerty**)
- Windows 10 limits the number of devices accessing its services, and according to https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/windows-8-iis-8-concurrent-requests-limit, there is also a concurrent connection limit on Windows Client OS's. Apparently it's the same for Windows 10 as for Windows 8.